# how do I use after_save for a model as well as for all its associated models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

I have a category model and it has association with say category_supply and category_experience model.If there is any changes in either category model or  its associated model (category_supply and category_experience) It should call after_save.So that I dont need to write after_save in each model

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `ActiveRecord::Observer` to watch for changes on the association models and then trigger a callback on the parent model. Here is an example:

```
class CategoryAssociationsObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  observe Supply, Experience
  def after_save(record)
    record.category.run_callbacks(:save) if record.category
    # I don't know if you can trigger just the `after_save` callback here
  end
end
```

See the `ActiveRecord::Observer` documentation for more information on its use: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Observer.

Comment: observe method is no longer supported in rails 3.Therefore we can't use multiple model supply and experience in the same observer.

Comment: What makes you think the `observe` method is no longer supported? `ActiveRecord::Observer` inherits from `ActiveModel::Observer`, which defines an `observe` method on l. 187 here: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/activemodel/lib/active_model/observing.rb. Observers and the `observe` method are NOT deprecated, even in Rails 4.